# Triggers Not Firing Over ODBC

Tags: c#, odbc, oledb, visual-foxpro

I have a class in C# that is attempting to delete a record in a FoxPro DBF file using OleDB. I can add records without a problem, however I get the following error when I want to delete, "Trigger Failed In Cntref1", with Cntref1 being the table I am attempting to delete from.

Here is the C# method;

```
    private bool DeleteContractRefDBF(int contractID, string whatFile)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(contractID.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(whatFile);
        try
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbfString"].ConnectionString;
            using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                dbfCon.Open();
                var dbfCmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM ? WHERE cr1_id=?", dbfCon);
                dbfCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                dbfCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whatFile", whatFile);
                dbfCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contractID", contractID);
                dbfCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Updating DBF (Show Dan): " + ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

ContractID is 7, which does exist and the whatFile is Cntref1, the correct Table.

Does anyone know the reason I would receive this error?

Comment: It says "trigger failed in CNtref1". Did you check what does trigger code contain? Probably it is a referential integrity trigger containing code to prevent deletion of a parent row if rows in a child table exist.

Comment: BTW it would be ExecuteNonQuery() and you don't need Parameters.Clear();